# How can I properly manage dependencies of nltk?

Tags: python, nltk, python-packaging

I use `from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize` which needs `punkt`. In code you can download it with `nltk.download('punkt')`.

I do have `nltk` as a requirement, but there is no target `nltk[punkt]`. Is there another way I set this in my `setup.py` as a requirement? What is the recommended way of dealing with this data dependency of nltk?

### Current "solution"

Currently, I just call `nltk.download('punkt')` within the function ... hence every single time I call this function, it is slowed down.